# How can I capture one line of data which is sent from MCU to PC?

Tags: microcontroller, java

I have a MCU (Arduino) that is connected through USB serial to PC. I am trying to get a reliable and accurate data when it is transmitted from MCU. I only need 1 line of data. More often than not I got shuffled or broken data. I have been trying to change my codes on both side PC and MUC like timing, set amount of time to read and write. However, I couldn't get it to work. The below are Java code on PC and C code on MCU that I got from https://www.xanthium.in/. I just edited it little bit.

```java
package serialportsavail;

import com.fazecast.jSerialComm.*;
public class SerialPortsAvail
{
   public static void main (String[] Args)
   {
     SerialPort [] AvailablePorts = SerialPort.getCommPorts();
     
     int i = 0;
       // use the for loop to print the available serial ports
         for(SerialPort S : AvailablePorts)
              System.out.println(i++ + "  " + S.getDescriptivePortName());
         
    //Open the first Available port
        SerialPort MySerialPort = AvailablePorts[0];
        
        int BaudRate = 9600;
        int DataBits = 8;
        int StopBits = SerialPort.ONE_STOP_BIT;
        int Parity   = SerialPort.NO_PARITY;

        //Sets all serial port parameters at one time
        MySerialPort.setComPortParameters(BaudRate,
                                          DataBits,
                                          StopBits,
                                            Parity);

        //Set Read Time outs
        MySerialPort.setComPortTimeouts(SerialPort.TIMEOUT_READ_BLOCKING, 
                                         3000, 
                                            0); 

        MySerialPort.openPort(); //open the port


                //Reading from COM port using Java

        try 
        {
            while (true)
            {
              byte[] readBuffer = new byte[100];

              int numRead = MySerialPort.readBytes(readBuffer,
                                                   readBuffer.length);

              System.out.print("Read " + numRead + " bytes -");

              //Convert bytes to String
              String S = new String(readBuffer, "UTF-8"); 

              System.out.println("Received -> "+ S);

            }
        } 
        catch (Exception e) 
        {
              e.printStackTrace(); 
        }

       // MySerialPort.closePort(); //Close the port
   }
}
```

========= C code========

```
void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(9600); // opens serial port, sets data rate to 9600 bps 8N1
}

void loop()
{
  char TextToSend[] = "Hello to Java from Arduino UNO";

  char NumToSend[] = "120489";

  Serial.print(TextToSend); // sends a \n with text
  Serial.println(NumToSend); // sends a \n with text
  delay(3000);
}
```

========== output from my PC
[image: output from my pc]

Comment: I see neither *shuffled* nor *broken*: Please provide (access to) a specification of `SerialPort..readBytes(buffer, bufferLength)`.

Comment: I recommend not to use blocking mode with timeout on the receiver side. Collect all coming data in a string until it contains the end of line symbol \n and then print it to System.out.

Comment: @greybeard Yes, you are right, they are shuffled. It took me awhile to see that. SerialPort is a class that return com port and you can get more information by using it methods. For example  you will port name when add this method ( getSystemPortName() ). readBytes is a method of serialport that read data in bytes when arrriving at the com port. I hope I answered your question.

Comment: Try using `openPort​(safetySleepTime, sendQSize, receiveQSize)`with a bigger receive queue size. Why, if you `need 1 line of data`, do you transmit in a loop? Set up the PC to read, then send *one* line.

Comment: While I didn't ask a question, I was thinking of a hyperlink like [`int com.fazecast.jSerialComm.SerialPort.readBytes​(byte[] buffer, long bytesToRead)`](https://fazecast.github.io/jSerialComm/javadoc/com/fazecast/jSerialComm/SerialPort.html#readBytes-byte:A-long-) in the body of your question.

Comment: @greybeard My goal is to transmit data from MCU to the PC. I have tried a few motheds such inputsteam read(), blockmode. I have tried to transmit 1 or 2 time (not forever loop) from the MCU, but It still didn't work. On the PC side never receiver the full data, always lost the first half.